# Create Linked-Integration-Runtime form a self-hosted integration runtime in CD pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I hve two ADF pipelines in different environments i.e Dev and Test. The Dev ADF has a self-hosted integration runtime which was created manually. The ADF in Dev has a LinkedService (SQL) that connects to local server using the self-hosted integration-runtime.

I have a CD pipeline where I am deploying ADF to Test using ARM templates and have a step which creates a linked integration service as follows:

```
az config set extension.use_dynamic_install=yes_without_prompt

az datafactory integration-runtime linked-integration-runtime create --factory-name "proj-dev-adf" 
'--integration-runtime-name "OnPrem-SHIR" --resource-group "proj-datalake-dev-rg" --name "dummyIR" 
--data-factory-name "proj-test-adf" --location "West Europe" --subscription-id $(SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
```

This code above, creates a linked integration runtime and I can see it in linked IRS:
[image]

But these linked IRS cannot be seen anywhere in test adf.

Can someone please help meto fix this: I just want to use the selfhosted IR in Dev ADF, in all other (ADF test and prod) wihtout manually creating any linked IR. I should be able to use the selfhosted IR (by first creating linked IR, using linked IR for sql link service).

Thanks